# Is there a possibility to use the value of a Variable in a String?

Tags: excel, vba

First of all i want to thank you in advance :)

I don't have any experience in VBA (only coded a few lines in Python and Java a few years ago) but got the task to create a macro that creates a new sheet where are stored the current calendar week + the week 3 weeks after in it. e.g.: `Steuerliste_neues_System_KW_25-28.xlsx`

Currently I'm not able to get even the current week in it...

This is my current code:

```
Sub Main()
kw_ermitteln
End Sub

'Kallenderwoche ermitteln
Public Sub kw_ermitteln()
    'kw = DINKw("DD.MM.YYYY")
    kw = DINKw(Range("I1"))
    Dim kwString As String
    kwString = CStr(kw)
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=".../Steuerliste_neues_System_KW_" + kwString + ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close


End Sub
'Function zur ermittlung der KW
Function DINKw(dat As Date) As Integer
    Dim kw As Integer
    kw = Int((dat - DateSerial(Year(dat), 1, 1) + ((Weekday(DateSerial(Year(dat), 1, 1)) + 1) _
    Mod 7) - 3) / 7) + 1
    If kw = 0 Then
        kw = DINKw(DateSerial(Year(dat) - 1, 12, 31))
    ElseIf kw = 53 And (Weekday(DateSerial(Year(dat), 12, 31)) - 1) Mod 7 <= 3 Then
        kw = 1
    End If
    DINKw = kw
End Function
```

But my problem with it is, that the new Excel data will just be named `Steuerliste_neues_System_KW_.xlsx`

I'm ready to learn so thanks again.

Comment: `DINKw` cannot return a value `CStr()` of which is an empty string. Are you sure this is your actual code?

Comment: If I change `kw = DINKw(Range("I1"))` to `kw = DINKw(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value)` I get the correct result. Please note, that I stored the current date in Cell A1 of Worksheet 1.

Comment: @GSerg: if the value of kw is 25, kwString will be "25" after `kwString = CStr(kw)`.

Comment: @QualiaCommunications: nice this worked out! Thanks a lot :) 

So was the problem that i hadn't told my code correctly where to look at?

Comment: @QualiaCommunications And what value should `kw` have such that `kwString = CStr(kw)` becomes an empty string, which is what ends up in the `Filename`?

Comment: @Tarik67TK No, the problem was that this is not your actual code. Regardless of what range you are looking at, it is impossible with `Function DINKw(dat As Date) As Integer` to have an empty string after `CStr(result of that function)`. If `DINKw` indeed has this signature, then there must be `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in your code that is not shown here.

Comment: @GSerg: I got the code for the calendar week from [this][source].
Besides that I don't really understand what mean or are after. 
But at least my question got answered and I'm continuing with my code :) 
So thanks both of you for your time 

[source]:https://www.excel-inside.de/beispiele_vba/vba-datum-zeit/253-kalenderwochedin